# Group by and sum

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am having trouble getting the sum of enrollment where the business_code is the same.  My code is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lb.building_code ,  lb.bus_code, gl.building_name, gl.bus_name, SUM(gl.enrollment) AS enrollment 
  FROM table1 AS gl 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN table 2 AS lb ON gl.building_key = lb.building_key
  where gl.bus_name = 'Business'
  and gl.year_cd = 2010
  GROUP BY lb.building_code,  lb.bus_code, gl.building_name, gl.bus_name, gl.enrollment
```

Current output:

```
building_code   bus_code    bus_name      enrollment  
4581             0000       Business A    12
4581             0000       Business A    13
4581             0109       Business B    100
4581             0109       Business B    120 
4581             0209       Business C    130 
4581             0402       Business D    35
```

Desired output:

```
 building_code   bus_code    bus_name      enrollment  
    4581             0000       Business A    25
    4581             0109       Business B    220
    4581             0209       Business C    130 
    4581             0402       Business D    35
```

Comment: Try removing enrollment from your group by statement.

Comment: Why do you have `DISTINCT` *and* `GROUP BY`? And why a `RIGHT JOIN` when you are filtering the outer table in your `WHERE` clause, making it an `INNER JOIN` anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `gl.building_name, gl.enrollment` from the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
  lb.building_code ,  
  lb.bus_code, 
  gl.bus_name, 
  SUM(gl.enrollment) AS enrollment 
FROM table1 AS gl 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN table 2 AS lb ON gl.building_key = lb.building_key
where gl.bus_name = 'Business'
  and gl.year_cd = 2010
GROUP BY lb.building_code,  lb.bus_code, gl.bus_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT lb.building_code,  
         lb.bus_code, 
         gl.bus_name,       
         SUM(gl.enrollment) AS enrollment 
  FROM table1 AS gl 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN table 2 AS lb ON gl.building_key = lb.building_key
  where gl.bus_name = 'Business'
  and gl.year_cd = 2010
  GROUP BY lb.building_code, 
           lb.bus_code, 
           gl.bus_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider two re-writes. One, if you meant this to be an outer join (so include rows from table2 that aren't in table1), change the order, make it a left join, move the where clauses for table1 into the join clause, remove the distinct, and remove the non-grouped column from the group by:

```
SELECT lb.building_code, lb.bus_code, gl.building_name, 
  gl.bus_name, SUM(gl.enrollment) AS enrollment 
FROM dbo.table2 AS lb
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.table1 AS gl 
  ON gl.building_key = lb.building_key
  AND gl.bus_name = 'Business'
  AND gl.year_cd = 2010
GROUP BY lb.building_code, lb.bus_code, gl.building_name, gl.bus_name;
```

(For the vast majority of people, a `LEFT JOIN` is far more intuitive than a `RIGHT JOIN`.)

If you really don't expect to have any rows from table2 that aren't in table1, then don't write this as an outer join in the first place:

```
SELECT lb.building_code, lb.bus_code, gl.building_name, 
  gl.bus_name, SUM(gl.enrollment) AS enrollment 
FROM dbo.table2 AS lb
INNER JOIN dbo.table1 AS gl 
  ON gl.building_key = lb.building_key
WHERE gl.bus_name = 'Business'
  AND gl.year_cd = 2010
GROUP BY lb.building_code, lb.bus_code, gl.building_name, gl.bus_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

Since you are using right outer join so don't forget to add IsNull in SUM aggregator function to handle the unmatched data from table 2

```
SELECT lb.building_code ,  lb.bus_code, gl.bus_name, SUM(Isnull(gl.enrollment,0)) AS enrollment 
  FROM table1 AS gl 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN table 2 AS lb ON gl.building_key = lb.building_key
  where gl.bus_name = 'Business'
  and gl.year_cd = 2010
  GROUP BY lb.building_code ,  lb.bus_code, gl.bus_name
```