# SQL Server Sum of column1 of all distinct values of column2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the SUM of column1 of all Distinct values of column2. Is it possible?

Comment: wouldn't a sum(column1) of group by column2 do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Group by and sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839586/group-by-and-sum)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Select SUM(ColA), ColB
from table
Group by ColB
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost wrote the query yourself in that sentence:

```
SELECT Column2, SUM(Column1) FROM Table GROUP BY Column2
```

Comment: I need the TOTAL sum of column1 but not by every value of column2. 
For ex:
Column1 | Column2
10 | 1
20 | 2
40 | 1

Comment: Could you add some sample data and expected output in your quesion? I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking...

...this adds all the values in column 1 for each distinct value in column 2 then gives a total of all values in column 1:

```
SELECT Column2,SUM(Column1) FROM Table GROUP BY Column2 with rollup
```

Note: If you want the rollup at the top of the output put distinct in it.

```
SELECT distinct Column2,SUM(Column1) FROM Table GROUP BY Column2 with rollup
```